# How to Hide Tracking Pixel

Tags: html, css

I have a tracking pixel that is unfortunately causing a small white bar at the bottom of my footer. What is the best way to hide the pixel?

I was thinking of putting it (and my other pixels) in a `position: absolute` div, which hides the bar properly but I'm not sure if that will prevent the pixel from working on some browsers.

Comment: put it in a div styled with `display:none`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [google Support:](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1347585?hl=en)

```
<img src="TRACKING-PIXEL-URL-GOES-HERE" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden">

<img src="TRACKING-PIXEL-URL-GOES-HERE" style="display:none">

<img src="TRACKING-PIXEL-URL-GOES-HERE" width="0" height="0">
```

Comment: That link now goes somewhere very different!

Comment: @ChuckLeButt wayback [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160429234906/https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1347585?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a `display: none` CSS declaration or alternatively you could give the footer a negative bottom margin value `margin-bottom: -1px`

Answer (score 1):

My tracking pixels were getting added automatically via javascript but all of them had a width and height of 1 defined `<img src="http://tracking.com/bla" width="1" height="1" />` so I hid them by targeting those attributes:

```
img[width="1"][height="1"] {
  display: none;
}
```

You could alternatively target the src:

```
img[src="http://tracking.com/bla"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the 1x1 size is an attempt to ensure that a smart browser will not optimize away the image request. With display: none, or size 0x0, the image request may never happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can also mask out in CSS a larger range of 1 pixel links, including data blob based images, like this:

```
*[src*='FIRST-PART-OF-TRACKING-PIXEL-URL-GOES-HERE'],
*[src*='data:image'] {
    display: none;
}
```