# Will visually hiding a tracking pixel using CSS prevent it from serving its purpose?

Tags: css

I'm planning to use this method adapted from [this Snook Research post](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility) to hide tracking pixels that come along with content that I'm loading. The purpose of the tracking pixel must be maintained. That only means that the image must load even though I want to be sure it's not causing even one pixel worth of unexpected formatting or displaying on the viewed part of the page.

```
.visuallyhidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0; 
}
```

Is this a good method for keeping tracking pixels out of my way?

Is there a better pure CSS approach?

Can you think of any reason why the providers of the tracking pixels would gripe over this?

I'm aware of other similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447973/how-to-hide-tracking-pixel) but I don't think they contain enough depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image should still be loaded, even though it is then hidden via CSS.

A simpler way of doing this would be:

```
.visuallyhidden {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Assuming it's a transparent 1x1 image, it would then be completely invisible for all intents and purposes.

Comment: To verify that the pixel is still *loading*, make sure it appears in the network tab in the chrome dev console...